# Multi select and button function together python kivy mobileapp

Tags: python, kivy

I am using `ListAdapter` to create a list of buttons and also use them as multiselect.

I want something like **button + multiselect**  that means; when I touch and hold a button for sometime, it should go for multi selection. On a single button click, it should work as a normal button.

Any idea how this is done in Kivy?

```
self.list_adapter = ListAdapter(data=[],selection_mode='multiple',
                                cls=ListItemButton, sorted_keys=[])
```

Comment: On a non-touch screen desktop/laptop is Click the first button and CTRL+Click or SHIFT+Click the other button. Have you try touch and hold the first button and drag to the second button?